# DNN 7 and asp.net server controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-6

We creating module for DNN7 and we are using [Christoc's DotNetNuke Module Development Template](http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/documentation) and I want to ask can we use asp.net server controller in our view.ascx?

Comment: Yes you can, are you having any issues with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Server controls in DotNetNuke modules. Check out some of the tutorials for Module Development at http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Module-Development.aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use any server control on .ascx in DNN.